# Solving quad root equation in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I'm trying to solve the following equation.

**(x * x) - 1 = 0**

The result should be +1 or -1. But when I try to solve it via sympy, the result is an empty output.

```
import sympy as sy

x = sy.Symbol('x')

sy.solve((x**2)-1, 0)

# sy.solve((x * x)-1, 0) and sy.solve((x * x), 1) returns the same result

>>> []
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's wrong is that you haven't bothered reading the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use,

```
sy.solve((x**2)-1,x)
```

Instead of,

```
sy.solve((x**2)-1,0)
```

The second argument x suggests that the equation should be solved for x. You are solving the equation for 0 which makes no sense.

Carefully read the documentation in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be

```py
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(x**2 - 1, x)
```

Read the documentation for the function [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Either do

```
sp.solve((x**2)-1, x)
```

or

```
sp.solve((x**2) - 1)
```

For further information, you can check out https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Answer (score 0):

In `nsolve` the second argument is an initial guess for the *value* of the variable that will make the univariate expression equal to zero:

```
>>> nsolve(x**2-1, 0)
1.00000000000000
>>> nsolve(x**2-1, -3)
-1.00000000000000
```

In `solve`, however, an initial guess is not needed since the equation will be solved symbolically:

```
>>> nsolve(x**2-1)
[-1, 1]
```

But `solve` can also handle multivariate expressions and in that case the second argument is used to indicate which variable you want to solve for.

```
>>> solve(x**2-c)
[{c: x**2}]
 >>> solve(x**2-c, x)
[-sqrt(c), sqrt(c)]
```

But you can solve for *anything* that appears in the expression, even numbers. That's why an error is not raised in your case (though perhaps zero *should* raise an error). Here are examples of solving for a number:

```
>>> solve(3*x**2-c, 3)
[c/x**2]
>>> solve(3*x**4-c, 4)
[log(c/3)/log(x)]
>>> solve(2*x**2-c, 2)
[LambertW(c*log(x))/log(x)]
```